# Rails Turbo Stream Before Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I'm trying out Turbo and Rails 7. Having a problem understanding where and how one would use the before action which Hotwire references:

```
<turbo-stream action="before" target="dom_id">
  <template>
    Content to place before the element designated with the dom_id.
  </template>
</turbo-stream>
```

I am using the example from the Hotwire website.

**show.html.erb:**

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<%= turbo_stream_from @room %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "room" do %>
  <%= render @room %>

  <div>
    <%= link_to "Edit this room", edit_room_path(@room) %> |
    <%= link_to "Back to rooms", rooms_path, "data-turbo-frame": "_top" %>

    <%= button_to "Destroy this room", @room, method: :delete %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div id="messages">
  <%= render @room.messages %>
</div>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "new_message", src: new_room_message_path(@room), target: "_top" %>
```

**_message.html.erb**

```
<p id="<%= dom_id message %>">
    <%= message.created_at.to_s(:short) %>: <%= message.content %>
</p>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New message</h1>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "new_message", target: "_top" do %>
  <%= form_with(model: [ @message.room, @message ],
      data: { controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" }) do |form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.text_field :content %>
      <%= form.submit "Send" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back", @message.room %>
```

**create.turbo_stream.erb**

```
<%= turbo_stream.append "messages", @message %>
```

How would one use the before action to insert the new message at the top of the list?

Answer (score 1):

To insert messages at the top of the list you should use the `prepend` instead of the `append` action. This would add the content of `<turbo-stream>` as the first child of `<div id="messages">`.

```
# prepend
<div id="messages">
  ... new message ...
  ... old messages ...
</div>

# append
<div id="messages">
  ... old messages ...
  ... new message ...
</div>
```

The `before` and `after` actions however are used to add something *outside* of the the specified element. Either before or after it.

```
# before
... new message ...
<div id="messages">
  ... old messages ...
</div>

# after
<div id="messages">
  ... old messages ...
</div>
... new message ...
```

See the [docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#stream-messages-and-actions).